# Suggestion for high school algebra textbooks with really good sets of problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, book-recommendation

I know this not a very 'mathematical' Question, but still its related to it, so i decided to just ask it here.

> Can anyone suggest me some good high school algebra books with some really good sets of problems?

Also, if anyone could help me with how to study maths effectively, it would be immensely helpful. To give you a bit of context, I was pretty good at maths through out my school upto standard X, but now I am in XI and things aren't going that great for me, though I am devoting more time and effort than I used to but the results don't reflect that at all.For instance, I scored a insane low of 6/66 in my last test.

I would be really thankful for any suggestion.

Comment: +1 to your question for your explicitly stating that you want the book to include lots of exercises.

Comment: Depends on where you live, cause the mentioned book may or may not be available in your locality.

Comment: For instance, RD Sharma is a popular book allover India, and also book by SN Dey is also pretty good, with lots of challenging problems. In context of competitive exams like iit jee, I recommend to work through ML Khanna.

Comment: @SubhamKarmakar thanks a lot for your suggestion, well I do own a copy of RD Sharma , will definitely have a look at the book by ML khanna..

Comment: Hi Kishor, I know this won't answer your question, but if you're doing very poorly in year 11 math, it's unlikely that the solution will be a better textbook than the one you have (unless the book is insanely bad). Usually in this kind of situation, it's crucial to get in-person help from a competent teacher.